# How do you change the axis for time in charts?

Tags: charts, google-sheets, google-visualization

Using google sheets, I am trying to plot times between 9pm and 3am (sleeping time every night), with the x axis being each calendar date/day.
But the scale puts items just after midnight at the bottom of the y-axis (y is the time axis, x axis is the day), because of the timing (0:10) is 10 minutes later than midnight and I want it to reflect that on the graph.
The two graphs are waking and sleeping times. 
Waking makes sense, sleeping does not: 
[image]
The only way seems to be put an if else and change format completely converting time format to integer and then multiplying to get a number close to 24 hrs (and then 1am is 25, 2 am is 26, etc).
[image]
Is there not a simpler was to change the axis for time? Does no one else log times either side of midnight?

The two images below show the formula, and the chart data: 
[image]
[image]

Comment: @WhiteHat, apologies, there is no code. I have added to more screenshots, showing the google sheets fromula, and the input into the chart.